# Trying to create a login pages by using severlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

login.jsp;

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<h1>user Login</h1>

</div>

<form action=loginServlet >
  <table>
  <tr><td>ENTER USERNAME:</td><td><input type= text name=username></td></tr>
  <tr><td>ENTER password:</td><td><input type=password name=password></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type= submit></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

login.servlet;

```
import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.railway.Utilityclass;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class loginservlet
 * utility
 */
public class loginservlet extends HttpServlet {
Utilityclass a = new Utilityclass();

    /**
     * @return 
     * @throws IllegalAccessException 
     * @throws InstantiationException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ServletException 
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected boolean doPost(String u,String p,   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ServletException, IOException {
          
        try {
             PrintWriter out =  response.getWriter();
             Connection con = Utilityclass.getConnection();
            Statement st =  (Statement) con.createStatement();
            String queryString = "SELECT username, password  FROM loginpage ";
            ResultSet results = st.executeQuery(queryString);

        while (results.next()) {
            String txtusername = results.getString("username");
            String txtpassword =  results.getString("password");
            
        if ((u.equals(txtusername)) && (p.equals(txtpassword))) {

          RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login sucessfullu");
           rd.forward(request, response);
            return true;
            }
            }
        out.println("<font color =red size 20>loginfailed!!<br>");
          
         
            return false;
            }
         catch (SQLException sql) {

           System. out.println(sql);
        }finally {
            ResultSet results = null;
        Connection con= null;
        Statement st = null;
            Utilityclass.closeConnection(results, st, con);
            
            
        }
        return false;

}

}
```

welcome.jsp;

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
login successfully
</h1>>
</body>
</html>
```

Error :

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [loginServlet]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.railway.loginServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1449)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:789)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:867)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1762)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I tried to login by using tomcat jsp and I stored the data in the sql. If I enter the username and password means It should go to login severlet and validate, then it needs to go to sql to check and then it has to login successfully... But while I trying to do this, I'm getting the above mentioned error, kindly help to solve this.

Comment: Make sure you have everything in the web.xml.  Otherwise, you need to use annotation.

Comment: `loginservlet` != `loginServlet`  Also, I think your signature for `doPost` is not correct.  Also better to query the DB using the received paramaters

Comment: The servlet is not in the correct package. That's why you're having to import that utility class. Also class names begin uppercase